# how to convert predicted decimal labels into text labels

Tags: python

I have a multilabel and multiclass classification problem. I have developed a classifier that predicts labels between 0 and 1 for all 5 labels. However, I want to convert decimal labels into text labels. for example, I have 4 labels such as: ("X", "y", "z", "k"). Actual labels contain binary labels, while predicted labels are in the range of (0 to 1).
Each sample can take either at least one label or note.

Examples are as follows:

- Actual label for sample 1: (0, 1, 1, 0) would like to convert to (non-x, y, z, non-k)
- predicted label: (0.0048, 0.098, 0.87, 0.004) would like to convert to (non-x, non-y, z, non-k).

in other words, I would like to convert numbers into text for both actual and predicted labels.

For actual: 0 converted to non, and 1 converted to yes

for predicted labels: all values between (0, 0.5) converted to non, and between (o.5 to 1) converted to yes.

I am using python.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this? Was there a particular problem when you tried to write the code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from lists to strings, do this:

```
list = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0.0048, 0.098, 0.87, 0.004]
e = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list)
print(str(e))
```